# Firebase Cloud Messaging: How to receive calls in OnMessage in C++ (iOS)?

Tags: c++, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Wordpress server that is to send messages to an iOS application using Firebase Cloud Messaging (currently not notifications, only messages with custom data). The message is sent using [Google's PHP API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) on the server side. Sending the message yields a `200` response code with body like this, `{"name": "projects/myapp/messages/864693047260522177"}`, so it seems to me that the sending has gone through ok (if I send incorrect JSON data I get a `400` response code).

In the iOS app I use the [C++ client code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/cpp/client) to receive messages. I have set up all dependencies and the `MessagingListener::OnTokenReceived()` function is called after I call `firebase::messaging::Initialize()` on application startup. This seems fine to me.

The problems is, however, that `MessagingListener::OnMessage()` is never called, neither when I send the messages myself (from the server), <strike>nor when I send test messages from the Firebase Console</strike>. What could I be missing to make this work?

**Update:** I suddenly received a test message sent from the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification). This message was sent several hours ago and suddenly it popped in. I have yet to receive my own messages.

Notes:

- I also use Google Analytics in C++ in the iOS application and it seems to work ok.
- I *think* I have set up everything correct in the iOS application, but I suppose I could have missed something (provisioning profile, push notifications enabled, etc.).
- The application is subscribed to the topic I send by calling `firebase::messaging::Subscribe("mm_actions")` after the Token is received.
- I see in the log output that subscribing to the topic `mm_actions` in C++ is altered to `/topics/mm_actions` behind the scenes. Success is printed thereafter. On the server I am not allowed to send `"topic": "/topics/mm_actions"`, but `"mm_actions"` is sent fine.
- C++ Firebase SDK version is `5.4.3`.
- Xcode/Swift versions are `10.1`/`4.0`.
- I have created a provisioning profile with push notifications enabled, downloaded it and double clicked it, so it should be installed. I cannot find it anywhere in Xcode though, so I don't know if it is actually used.
- My auth scope when fetching the Oauth2 token is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging`.
- I post the message to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myappid/messages:send`.

### C++ Client Code (iOS)

Firebase.h

```
namespace messaging
{
    struct MessagingListener : public firebase::messaging::Listener
    {
        ~MessagingListener() override;
        void OnMessage(const firebase::messaging::Message& message) override;
        void OnTokenReceived(const char* token) override;
    };

    extern MessagingListener gMessagingListener;
    void initialize();
}
```

Firebase.cpp

```
namespace messaging
{
    MessagingListener gMessagingListener;

    MessagingListener::~MessagingListener()
    {}

    // This function is never called for mye own messages and test messages
    // from the Firebase Console takes several hours to arrive.
    void MessagingListener::OnMessage(const firebase::messaging::Message& message)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "From: %s", message.from.c_str());
        fprintf(stdout, "Message ID: %s", message.message_id.c_str());
        fprintf(stdout, "Message type: %s", message.message_type.c_str());
        for (const auto& d : message.data)
        {
            std::string key = d.first;
            std::string val = d.second;
        }
    }

    // Always called after initialize() below
    void MessagingListener::OnTokenReceived(const char* token)
    {
        firebase::messaging::Subscribe("mm_actions");
    }

    // Called on application startup. Everything works fine.
    void initialize()
    {
        firebase::App* app = app::getInstance();
        assert(app);
        if (app)
        {
            firebase::InitResult result = firebase::messaging::Initialize(*app, &gMessagingListener);
            assert(result == firebase::InitResult::kInitResultSuccess);
        }
    }
}
```

### FCM Log Output in iOS App

```
2019-01-12 14:50:12.585965+0100 myapp[450:208682] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002000] FIRMessaging library version 3.2.2
2019-01-12 14:50:12.608186+0100 myapp[450:208682] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2019-01-12 14:50:15.713285+0100 myapp[450:208747] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002010] The subscription operation is suspended because you don't have a token. The operation will resume once you get an FCM token.
2019-01-12 14:50:19.120085+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM017000] Topic subscription request: sender=fAKBne8z1Ek:APA91bEV2R36cZXX_a8C0zTgw3zhJVb0hD02QT7Zex2Ou5Sddiq2c8OQIj5cU44hgC6WFB64Go02y-0fjYUYic2nESSLAOrmiBedg-tKSjMyIZuahPDv6N7n6aOs4vIw71sc6eeIibnd&app=com.mycompany.myapp&device=5622054262136970124&app_ver=1.0&X-gcm.topic=/topics/mm_actions&X-scope=/topics/mm_actions
2019-01-12 14:50:19.123922+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005000] Start connecting to FIRMessaging service.
2019-01-12 14:50:19.124284+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM015000] Opening secure socket to FIRMessaging service
2019-01-12 14:50:19.124643+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM015006] Secure socket to FIRMessaging service opened
2019-01-12 14:50:19.124992+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005001] Connected to FIRMessaging service.
2019-01-12 14:50:19.126362+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005017] RMQ: Sending GtalkLoginRequest with outgoing stream Id: 1.
2019-01-12 14:50:19.126782+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005023] Send msg: (null) type: -2 inStreamId: 0 outStreamId: 1
2019-01-12 14:50:19.127276+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005015] RMQ: Receiving GtalkLoginResponse with incoming stream Id: 1.
2019-01-12 14:50:19.127504+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005012] Logged onto MCS service.
2019-01-12 14:50:19.128014+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005017] RMQ: Sending GtalkHeartbeatPing with outgoing stream Id: 2.
2019-01-12 14:50:19.129285+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005023] Send msg: (null) type: 0 inStreamId: 1 outStreamId: 2
2019-01-12 14:50:19.129859+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005015] RMQ: Receiving GtalkIqStanza with incoming stream Id: 2.
2019-01-12 14:50:19.130287+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005015] RMQ: Receiving GtalkHeartbeatAck with incoming stream Id: 3.
2019-01-12 14:50:19.130584+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005019] RMQ: Server last received stream Id: 2.
2019-01-12 14:50:19.158348+0100 myapp[450:208641] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM004003] Successfully subscribed to topic /topics/mm_actions
2019-01-12 14:50:45.899272+0100 myapp[450:208682] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005023] Send msg: (null) type: 0 inStreamId: 3 outStreamId: 3
2019-01-12 14:50:45.900326+0100 myapp[450:208682] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005015] RMQ: Receiving GtalkHeartbeatAck with incoming stream Id: 4.
2019-01-12 14:50:45.901406+0100 myapp[450:208682] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005019] RMQ: Server last received stream Id: 3.
2019-01-12 14:51:15.115197+0100 myapp[450:208682] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005017] RMQ: Sending GtalkHeartbeatPing with outgoing stream Id: 4.
2019-01-12 14:51:15.115707+0100 myapp[450:208682] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005023] Send msg: (null) type: 0 inStreamId: 4 outStreamId: 4
2019-01-12 14:51:15.142261+0100 myapp[450:208682] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005015] RMQ: Receiving GtalkHeartbeatAck with incoming stream Id: 5.
2019-01-12 14:51:15.146010+0100 myapp[450:208682] 5.14.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM005019] RMQ: Server last received stream Id: 4.
```

### PHP Server Code

I omit the PHP code here since I get a `200` response from Google. I will paste it if it could help somehow, but I cannot see why. My request headers contains an Oauth2 token and my request body is like this:

```
{
    "message": {
        "topic": "mm_actions",
        "data": {
            "action": "sync_db"
        }
    }
}
```

I used [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send) to set up the JSON request body.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100 % sure why, but it suddenly started working after some time. Here is what *think* happened:

1. I added `firebase::messaging::Subscribe("mm_actions");` in `MessagingListener::OnTokenReceived()`. I had not done this at first so it is likely that this is what was missing initially.
2. Test messages from the Firebase Console then started coming through to `MessagingListener::OnMessage()`.
3. Messages from my server did not come through until I realised I had put in `"validate_only": true` in my JSON data, making the messages a dry-run. Removing this made everything work as expected.

So I learned the following:

1. You cannot send data messages without the devices being subscribed to the topic you send.
2. Data messages can be sent even though the user has rejected notifications.